# Link button to textbox in WPF at runtime

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls, textblock

Hey all i have created a few text boxes and also buttons to go along with them at run-time.

The code for the button is:

```
 Dim updateButton As New Button

 updateButton.Name = "button_" & ticketTheRowNum & "_" & ticketRowNum
 updateButton.Content = "UPDATE!"
 updateButton.Height = 26
 Canvas.SetTop(updateButton, 24 * ticketTheRowNum)
 Canvas.SetLeft(updateButton, 330 + lblNotes.Width)
 updateButton.Width = lblNotes.Width / 2 - 10
 updateButton.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)
 Grid.SetRow(updateButton, 0)
 Grid.SetColumn(updateButton, 0)
 Grid.SetZIndex(updateButton, 2500)
 cavTicket.Children.Add(updateButton)
```

And the code for the text box is this:

```
 Dim txtBlock As New TextBox

 txtBlock.Name = "txt_" & ticketTheRowNum & "_" & ticketRowNum
 txtBlock.Text = theHeader
 txtBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
 txtBlock.Width = lblNotes.Width - 5
 txtBlock.BorderThickness = New Thickness(0)
 txtBlock.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left
 txtBlock.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto
 tmpExpander.Content = txtBlock
```

Now the button and text box displays just fine on the WPF but I am unsure of how to hook the button up to have it know whats in the text box and save its content. Currently since I am creating these at run-time I don't have access like I would if its was already on the form before it ran (I would simply just call the buttons click event and then within that I would call the text box content and save it).

Comment: that's typically what you use XAML for; which is what WPF was made for, so you don't do anything like this.

Answer (score 1):

If both of your code blocks come from the same class then just add a private property txtBlock (by the way why block and not Box?). So when you will create your TextBox control it will then be visible to all the functions in your class including the button event handler.

But as NETscape said. WPF is all about XAML, binding, and WVVM. So if you want to avoid headaches use them ;)